# How do I solve the modal related errors I am having while using 4.0.0-alpha.6?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using the bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 version now.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

When using a drop down component in a modal window, the drop down layer does not close in mac / safari and firefox browsers.
It works fine in Chrome browser.

To be precise, when you click on the drop-down that opens, the layer closes, then release the mouse and the layer will open again.

I am looking for a workaround other than how to change the bootstrap version.
I am looking for the cause and solution of the error. Please Help

Here is the html code I tested:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown button</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason it has an `alpha` in its name is because it is unfinished. Use the finished one (`4.1+`) and the problem goes away. Ideally you should use latest stable. There are no backwards compat issues across all of `4.x` in Bootstrap. Only bug fixes and extra functionality.

Comment: Why are you not using the latest, which I believe, is like 4.1.2?

Comment: @KaseyChang
It is not easy to change the bootstrap version because other related libraries are being used together. Is it okay to use a different version of the script while keeping the bootstrap css version at 4.0.0-alpha.6? ex) css version: 4.0.0-alpha.6, js version: 4.1.3 or css version: 4.0.0-alpha.6, js version: 4.5

Comment: Actually, Bootstrap just released 4.5.0 while you're dawdling. Let's put it this way... Are you AFRAID of breaking things, even though you don't really know if anything will break, or have you already observed broken things? And did you test it with the latest? This problem will not solve itself.